# Integrating Java with .NET?

Tags: java, .net, integration, soa

So I need to integrate Java with .NET (it's a Project for College) and I was told to use JMS, Web Services, RMI, REST/JSon. The fact is that I don't know where to begin (because I don't know too much about SOA)... But my professor told me that I could use NetBeans because it has some Integration Tools that would make it easier for me and I can also use the Graphical Tool from BPEL, or I could use ServiceMix on GlassFish... I'm kind of lost. Any help? Thanks. :)

Comment: More information regarding the sort of integration would be useful.  For example, what sort of boundary do you need?  Do you need to call a Java library from .Net code (or vice-versa) directly?  Or will you have a Java client communicating with a .Net service over the network?

Comment: When you say you need to integrate Jave with .Net, do you mean you need to pass Java objects into a .Net application?

Comment: There is also [ICE](http://www.zeroc.com/forums/comments/194-ice-net.html). It's similar to RMI or CORBA. Another alternative is Thrift or a protocol-buffer stack. Happy ... schooling.

Comment: check this development platform which has the goodness of .net and java both altogether http://www.windev.com/

Answer (score 4):

Your professor is the one that sounds lost.

Start with one - it doesn't matter which one.

Web services are a good place to start, because they're based on HTTP.  Both Java EE and .NET understand HTTP well.

You have to write a client and a server.  You can demonstrate inter-operation between the two platforms by starting with a Java servlet as the server, running on a servlet/JSP engine like Tomcat, and then writing a .NET client that connects to the server and makes an HTTP GET or POST request and processes the response.

Then reverse the roles: write a .NET SOAP server, deploy it on IIS, and then write a Java client that makes a SOAP request and processes the response.

That will satisfy the spirit of the assignment and demonstrate the point.

Comment: I agree, Duffy. Thanks. I remember I've been using JBoss for Get and Post methods. I could start from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IFRAMEs to put together a final HTML page that sources content from both Java and .Net.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that you should take 'JMS' as a hint. Looks like your professor is asking you to learn about/experiment with integration patterns and middleware.

An excellent book on this has been written years ago: http://www.eaipatterns.com/

Spring Integration is available for Java and .NET as far as i know.

Comment: Thanks mkro. I'll check it out! :)